# Sublime Text build file for C++11

Tags: c++11, build, g++, sublimetext3

I'm currently trying to set up my build system in Sublime Text to compile C++11 Code and additionally use libpqxx library for some Postgres database stuff.

Right now, without C++11, my g++ command looks like this:

```
    "cmd": ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "-I/usr/include/pqxx", "-lpqxx", "-lpq"]
```

Which works fine.

Now I add `"-std=c++0x"` to the line, and it doesn't work. However, I wrote a simple testprogram that has `#include <regex>` in it, startet out with a default build file and added the C++11 flag to look like this:

```
    "cmd": ["g++", "-std=c++0x", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
```

It works fine.

I also tried running the build from terminal, using this line:

```
    g++ Connect.cpp -o Connect -std=c++0x -I/usr/include/pqxx -lpqxx, -lpq
```

But with no luck either.

Further I tried different places for the `-std=c++0x`. Right after `g++`, after the input and output file names, after the include, after the libary linking. And I trief to alter the std flag to `-std+gnu++11`, `-std=c++11`, `-std=gnu++0x`. Nothing helped.

What am I doing wrong?

(by the way my GCC/G++ has version 4.9, so there shouldn't be any problems with C++11 itself. The testfile.cpp without lipqxx include and linking works as mentioned before)

---

The solution: `-I/usr/include/pqxx` needed to be taken out.

Comment: Instead of adding the solution to the question itself, please make it an answer, with details of what you did and why, to help future visitors to the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the solution is to remove the `-I/usr/include/pqxx`. But why?

1. The file he wants to include is `/usr/include/pqxx/pqxx`.
   He is including it with `#include <pqxx/pqxx>` (He didnt provide that information on stackoverflow). With this include statement he doesn't need the additional include path since `/usr/include` is in the standard path.
2. But why is the build failing?

   ```
   % ~ cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -M test.cpp > test2              
   % ~ cpp -Wall -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/pqxx -M test.cpp > test
   % ~ cat test2 | sed "s/ \\\\//g" | sed "s/ /\n/g" | sort > test2  
   % ~ cat test | sed "s/ \\\\//g" | sed "s/ /\n/g" | sort > test
   % ~ diff test test2
   235d234
   < 
   270a270
   > /usr/include/c++/4.9.0/array
   404a405
   > /usr/include/c++/4.9.0/tuple
   496d496
   < /usr/include/pqxx/tuple
   ```

   The `-M` option outputs a makefile.compatible list of headerfiles. The rest is just reformating to have a nicer diff.

Result: with `-I/usr/include/pqxx` the `pqxx/tuple` is included instead of the standard c++ `tuple`. That causes the compilation errors he didnt provide here.